# IntelliJ can't load Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, intellij-idea, java-11

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community 2020.2.3.

My project is built around Kotlin 1.3.30 and Java 11.

I've upgraded one of my dependecy to java 11 too, and after that, the IDE shows the dependency under "External Libraries", it build the app without errors, Maven build it from terminal without error, but the IDE shows unresolved references on each occurrency of the classes, functions and imports of that library.

I already tried to empty the cache or deleting idea files and importing again the project, but none of those worked.

Any tips?

Comment: Maybe 'mvn clean' - but you have probably already done so, right?

Comment: Yes, I already done that

Comment: This sentence: `Maven build it from terminal without error, but shows unresolved references on each occurrency of the classes, functions and imports of that library.` I don't understand... Does build work or not ... if references missing then the build does not work... it would be helpful to see the error output....

Comment: @khmarbaise the build works but the IDE shows erros. Those errors are unresolved references. I don't know what's happening, that's why I opened this.

Comment: Show us the screenshots of the problem in a full IDE window so that the source has is visible and project tool window.

Comment: Are there any exceptions in idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action) file?

Comment: Do you use the Java 9 module system in your project?

Comment: Gimby I do not use that. @Andrey classes are marked in red and I already looked at logs, no exceptions.

Comment: From what library do you see such unresolved classes? How do you add it to project?

Comment: Try deleting [IDE system directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#system-directory) and re-import project using File | New | project from Existing Sources action and select pom.xml file to import from. If problem remains, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project and idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action) file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CTRL+SHIFT+A` and look for `Load Maven Changes` or `CTRL+SHIRT+O` to do the same thing

Comment: Is those classes auto generated by maven? Do you need to `Generate Sources and Update Folders`?

Comment: No, those are not auto generated classes.

Comment: @abierto Intellij IDEA Community 2020.2.4 released today. Perhaps can try it to test out